# Finding the max/min of a discrete image

Tags: matlab

Given a discrete image, e.g.:
[image: example image]

how can one find the **local** minima/maxima locations?

EDIT:
Maximum and minimum in terms of derivative, not absolute max/min. In the example below the results should be two lines at the bottom, and some local peaks at the top.

Note that deriving is not that simple since the zero locations falls between pixels, and zero crossing in a 2d image is more complected than a 1d signal.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you are fastest if you just implement it yourself. Just loop over the points and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the linear index of the max/min (second output) and then use [ind2sub](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to get the row and column coordinates.

```
%Assuming your image is stored in matrix I
[Vmax, Imax] = max(I(:));
[Rmax, Cmax] = ind2sub(size(I), Imax);

[Vmin, Imin] = min(I(:));
[Rmin, Cmin] = ind2sub(size(I), Imin);
```

Comment: In that case: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12275-extrema-m-extrema2-m